# postgresql удаленное подключение

Tags: java, postgresql

Помогите подключиться к базе данных удаленно.
пробовал настроить сервер, но не могу понять как подключиться к нему удаленно

настроил файл pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

# /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
hostssl  all  postgres  0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

в postgresql.conf уже настройки стояли, поэтому ничего не пришлось менять

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

есть пользователь postgres со всеми правами 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть сервер на localhost с стандартным портом 5432

создать сервер и подключиться по внешнему ип не получается

пробовал так же законектится с java через jdbc driver, на localhost конектится нормально, по внешнему нет
вот пример кода:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Main {
    //  Database credentials
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://213.111.170.223:5432/postgres";
    static final String USER = "postgres";
    static final String PASS = "root";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Testing connection to PostgreSQL JDBC");

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver is not found. Include it in your library path ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("PostgreSQL JDBC Driver successfully connected");
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You successfully connected to database now");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection to database");
        }
    }


}
```

сама ошибка подключения

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Подсоединение отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:138)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
    ... 11 more
```

порты на роутере и на компьютере открыты

может проблема во внешнем ip и нужно вводить что то иное? я что то не так делаю?

Comment: Попробуйте для начала подключиться через стороннюю программу, например http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net, возможно, тут не в Java дело совсем.

Comment: а есть какой то мануал по установке? с пхп не знаком, поэтому хз как настраивать, в инете ничего не нашел

Comment: Это лишь пример. Можете найти другое ПО для работы с Postgre. Мануал по указанному ПО есть на их оф. сайте - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/master/INSTALL

Comment: ну у меня есть уже встроенное pgAdmin или это не то, что нужно?

Comment: Можете через него попробовать получить удаленный доступ к БД.

Comment: И еще: БД точно разывается *'postgres'*? Никакие фаерволы не блокируют доступ?

Comment: ну там у меня уже есть подключение к локальному сервер
да, так и называется,фаерволы не блокируют

Comment: к слову как я уже писал, по внешнему ip подключиться не получается через pgadmin

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84620/discussion-between-kosmos-and-).